# How to log in via OAuth so a cron job can run

Tags: php, javascript, oauth, trello

Not 100% sure I worded the title correctly, but here is what I want to do.

I have written a small page that is mostly JS & a small PHP scraper.  The script runs, connects to Trello, based on what it finds, it scrapes another site using the PHP scraper, and then updates some cards in Trello.

This is fine as a page I can load up in a browser, but I want to set it up as a page that runs as a cron job on our server.  I don't know how to modify my script to automatically log into Trello.  I know I could run it once, authorize for 30 days etc., but ideally I don't want to keep having to do that.  I'm a little unfamiliar with this, so any reco's on how best to approach it are welcome.

**Moved from webapps

Comment: Are you talking to Trello via the API, or screen scraping?

Comment: Via the API, I'm scraping one of our own sites.  Basically our sites update regularly, I want to past the update to the appropriate card every morning automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easiest to generate a non-expiring API token, instead of trying to simulate logging into Trello.

First, generate an application key at

https://trello.com/1/appKey/generate

Then, generate a non-expiring read/write token at

[https://trello.com/1/authorize?key=**substitutewithyourapplicationkey**&name=My+Application&expiration=**never**&response_type=token&scope=read,write](https://trello.com/1/authorize?key=substitutewithyourapplicationkey&name=My%20Application&expiration=never&response_type=token&scope=read,write)

That should be enough to do board and card `GET`s and `PUT`s, and you don't have to worry about getting a new token, because it won't ever expire.

For example, you could read a board:

`GET https://api.trello.com/1/boards/id_of_board?key=substitutewithyourapplicationkey&token=substitutewithyournonexpiringtoken`

or modify a card

`PUT https://api.trello.com/1/cards/id_of_card?desc=New%20Description&key=substitutewithyourapplicationkey&token=substitutewithyournonexpiringtoken`

For more details, see https://trello.com/docs and https://trello.com/api

Comment: Thank you.  The bigger problem is my not knowing what to do with that new, non-expiring key.  I tried replacing it in my javascript link but that doesn't work.

Comment: Any idea how I go about using that key to give my page permanent access to my Trello account? Do I use it in PHP? Somewhere in the javascript? I've spent the last hour trying to figure it out, but totally stuck.